# Why can I not install Keynote on my MacbookPro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keynote

Why there is no install for KeyNote in this model of the MacBook Pro running 10.13 High Sierra ?

[image]

*Editor's note*
MBP 2011 Last supported macOS 10.13.x

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned at the bottom of https://www.apple.com/keynote/features/

> Pages for Mac, Numbers for Mac, and Keynote for Mac are available on the Mac App Store. **macOS Catalina or later required**

so if you haven't installed Keynote before you may not be able to download it from the App Store.

Alternativly you can use the web version of Keynote on [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com) or try an application like [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org).

Comment: You'd think there would (or should) be something similar to the iOS "...but you can have this older version". My google-fu is failing me on if it's possible.

Comment: I think the reason for no concrete documentation is it’s complicated @Tetsujin and Apple wants to be free to introduce breaking changes to the file format and features and a concrete matrix sets expectations that people understandably then expect support and longevity.

Answer (score 4):

"Why" questions are often very difficult to answer unless the manufacturer publicly states their reasons.

However, in this particular case, the reason is publicly declared - your Mac is designated as 'obsolete' & therefore has no further support.
[Obtaining service for your Apple product after an expired warranty](https://support.apple.com/HT201624)
Apple publishes this list, updated periodically, as a list of Macs which still have hardware service support, but software support goes almost hand in hand with this list.

Generally (but not absolutely) any Mac will have full support for its first 5 years then limited support for the next 5. This tends to mean that after 5 years, whilst you can continue running the Mac, software availability will gradually drop behind. Once you can no longer upgrade to the latest macOS, then you probably have 3 years of continued security & OS updates. After that, you're on your own.

A consequence of this is that High Sierra is now more than 3 entire OS revisions old & is completely out of support.
This historical support does appear in recent years to have shortened, but this does happen periodically. Sometimes the underlying technology in a major OS release means that older hardware & OSes can no longer conform to the newer practises.
This happened in two steps this time, first at Mojave & then with a bigger step to Catalina.

I suppose that leaves us with another "why" question, which we can't answer -
"Why can I not get an older version of an app from the App Store?".

Comment: When hardware being "out of support" means that the vendor isn't working on updates for it anymore, that makes sense. When it means "muahahaha, all your stuff that used to work just stops working for no other reason than because we said so!" then something is deeply wrong with the world. Running software that's been published for free, or that you purchased, on hardware you own, shouldn't require any third party's "support".

Comment: @hobbs, i appreciate your comment. I have an important presentation on 26th of January and now my mac is making its software update drama! Feeling sad for apple and his holiness Mr. Steve Jobs. Walter Isaacson invested his precious time to write abour Mr. Jobs?

Comment: You can hardly blame Steve Jobs that you're 8 years late in installing an app. Jobs was always insistent that to maintain quality you had to retain tight control over both hardware, OS & software. This is a direct result of that legacy. At the opposite end of that decision-making scale is Microsoft's Windows XP… which just wouldn't die, & held up Windows' progress for a decade.

Comment: And today is the day when the signing certificates for many of the old OS and apps expire breaking offline installers that used to be trusted or valid.